# How to detect write failure in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

As a simple example, consider the network equivalent of /dev/zero, below. (Or more realistically, just a web server sending a large file.)

If a client disconnects early, you get a barrage of log messages:

```
WARNING:asyncio:socket.send() raised exception.
```

But I'm not finding any way to catch said exception. The hypothetical server continues reading gigabytes from disk and sending them to a dead socket, with no effort on the client's part, and you've got yourself a DoS attack.

The only thing I've found from the docs is to yield from a read, with an empty string indicating closure. But that's no good here because a normal client isn't going to send anything, blocking the write loop.

What's the right way to detect failed writes, or be notified that the TCP connection has been closed, with the streams API or otherwise?

Code:

```
from asyncio import *
import logging

@coroutine
def client_handler(reader, writer):
    while True:
        writer.write(bytes(1))
        yield from writer.drain()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
loop = get_event_loop()
coro = start_server(client_handler, '', 12345)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: **Update:** This is now [fixed](https://github.com/python/asyncio/pull/280) upstream in the `asyncio` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little bit strange, but you can actually allow an exception to reach the `client_handler` coroutine by forcing it to yield control to the event loop for one iteration:

```
import asyncio
import logging

@asyncio.coroutine
def client_handler(reader, writer):
    while True:
        writer.write(bytes(1))
        yield  # Yield to the event loop
        yield from writer.drain()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(client_handler, '', 12345)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)
loop.run_forever()
```

If I do that, I get this output when I kill the client connection:

```
ERROR:asyncio:Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<client_handler() done, defined at aio.py:4> exception=ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 238, in _step
    result = next(coro)
  File "aio.py", line 9, in client_handler
    yield from writer.drain()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/streams.py", line 301, in drain
    raise exc
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 700, in write
    n = self._sock.send(data)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

I'm really not quite sure why you need to explicitly let the event loop get control for the exception to get through - don't have time at the moment to dig into it. I assume some bit needs to get flipped to indicate the connection dropped, and calling `yield from writer.drain()` (which can short-circuit going through the event loop) in a loop is preventing that from happening, but I'm really not sure. If I get a chance to investigate, I'll update the answer with that info.

Answer (score 5):

I did some digging into the `asyncio` source to expand on [dano's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32190862/5256417) answer on why the exceptions aren't being raised without explicitly passing control to the event loop. Here's what I've found.

Calling `yield from wirter.drain()` gives the control over to the [`StreamWriter.drain`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l292) coroutine. This coroutine [checks](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l301) for and raises any exceptions that that the [`StreamReaderProtocol`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l204) set on the [`StreamReader`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l307). But since we passed control over to [`drain`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l292), the protocol hasn't had the chance to set the exception yet. [`drain`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l292) then gives control over to the [`FlowControlMixin._drain_helper`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#l192) coroutine. This coroutine the returns immediately because some more flags haven't been set yet, and the control ends up back with the coroutine that called `yield from wirter.drain()`.

And so we have gone full circle without giving control to the event loop to allow it handle other coroutines and bubble up the exceptions to `writer.drain()`.

`yield`ing before a `drain()` gives the transport/protocol a chance to set the appropriate flags and exceptions.

Here's a mock up of what's going on, with all the nested calls collapsed:

```
import asyncio as aio

def set_exception(ctx, exc):
  ctx["exc"] = exc

@aio.coroutine
def drain(ctx):
  if ctx["exc"] is not None:
    raise ctx["exc"]

  return

@aio.coroutine
def client_handler(ctx):
  i = 0
  while True:
    i += 1
    print("write", i)
    # yield # Uncommenting this allows the loop.call_later call to be scheduled.
    yield from drain(ctx)

CTX = {"exc": None}

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
# Set the exception in 5 seconds
loop.call_later(5, set_exception, CTX, Exception("connection lost"))
loop.run_until_complete(client_handler(CTX))
loop.close()
```

This should probably fixed upstream in the Streams API by the `asyncio` developers.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I have been struggling with a remote socket that forcibly closes the connection and I wasn't sure what to do. I catch the exception and add logic to deal with it. Looks like I should be using a connection callback instead. But I wanted to use the Stream API to avoid callbacks!

Answer (score 1):

The stream based API doesn't have a callback you can specify for when the connection is closed. But the Protocol API does, so use it instead: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#connection-callbacks

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but I did say "or otherwise" so I guess it's fair. To me, a warning means I'm doing something wrong. But you're saying there's no "right" way to do it with streams?